# How to deploy pgadmin4 docker image on azure web app?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, pgadmin-4, azure-webapps

I am unable to run docker image **dpage/pgadmin4** on azure web app (Linux) which is available on docker hub.

I have installed Docker in my Linux machine and was able to run that docker image locally. Then I created Web app in Azure with options as given below:

- OS: Linux
- Publish: Docker Image
- App service plan: Linux app service

After creating web app, I added two env variables in App Settings section:

```
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL : user@domain.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD : SuperSecret
```

Finally login screen is visible but when I enter above credentials, it doesn't work and keeps redirecting to login page.

Update: If login is working properly, screen appears as shown below.
!([pgadmin initial screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBKjp.png))

Answer (score 3):

After several retries i once got an message (CSRF token invalid) displayed in the right-top corner of the login screen.

For CSRF to properly work there must be some serverside state? So I activated the "ARR affinity" in the "General Settings" on the azure "Configuration".

I also noticed in the [explamples on documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html) the two environment-variables `PGADMIN_CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL` (which is in the example set to '10') and `PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION` (which is in the example set to 'True').

After enabling "ARR" and setting `PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION` to `False` the login started to work. I have no idea what `PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION` is actually doing, so please take that with caution.

If thats not working for you, maybe setting `PGADMIN_CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL` to `10` and enabling console debug logging can give you a clue whats happening.

Answer (score 1):

`PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION` allows pgAdmin4 to create session cookies based on IP address. It should be disabled in dynamic IP address hosting environments, where the IP address could change.

Source: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/config_py.html and search for ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, I do the test and find that it's really a strange thing. When I deploy the docker image dpage/pgadmin4 in Azure service Web App for Container through Azure CLI and set the app settings, there is no problem to log in with the user and password. But when I deploy it through the Azure portal, then I meet the same thing with you.

Not sure what is the reason, but the solution is that set the environment variables `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL` and `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD` through the Azure CLI like below:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --settings PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL="user@domain.com" PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD="SuperSecret"
```

If you really want to know the reason, then you can make feedback to Microsoft. Maybe it's a bug or some special settings.

**Update**

The screenshot of the test on my side here:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share me screenshot which appears in your web app after login with username and password as I am trying to figure it out since one week and not able to resolve.

Comment: @Rushabh I add the screenshot. Log in with the user and password.

Comment: I have updated one screenshot of pgadmin4 client which is working locally fine. I guess your screenshot is showing that its not properly working post login. 
Right now I am not able to see my updated screenshot as I have less credits.

I am also trying to follow your steps and creating web app for container using Azure CLI and docker hub image as container to be used.

Comment: @Rushabh Yes, it just shows as the screenshot shows and it works fine when I deploy the image in the vm. Not sure why it cannot load the dashboard when it deploys in the web app.

Comment: So even you are stuck again as I thought. Don't worry, I will definitely provide feedback to Microsoft regarding this. Please let me know if you find any more on this web app issue.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I am trying this a year later and still get the same result as @CharlesXu

Comment: @dashambles I didn't get the same error. So I don't know why you got it.